# Обратная связь в django и панель администратора

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-orm

---

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь. есть две модели:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True)
    number_of_guests = models.IntegerField(default=None,)

class Guest(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, null=True, default=None)
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Как можно в стандартной панели администратора у Table, вывести всех, кто ссылается на него из Guest?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Использовать [инлайны](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

Comment: В стандартной панели администратора есть два вида, вывод списка обьектов модели и редактирование конкретного обьекта. Уточните, в какой из этих видов вы хотите вывести связанные. И добавте в вопрос ваш admin.py.